# How can I use thrift server Play framework java on sockets?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, thrift

Is there a formal way of Using Apache Thrift in Java Play Framework with out using the Finagle-Thrift for Scala. I don't want to use web Sockets but use regular Sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my findings when it comes to Play Framework and thrift Sockets which clearly work for me.

1. Instead of using Thrift direct we shall use Finagle-thrift. It's an upgraded custom fault tolerant extension of Thrift by Twitter. It's built in Scala but in this case we shall use Scrooge to generate Scala or Java. In this case we shall use Java.
2. The version of Java is 8 or latest.
3. Your build.sbt file will look like this;[link](https://github.com/chrisp22/hello-finagle-thrift-java/blob/master/build.sbt)
4. Your serve Application should call the generated Scala Interface to the Java Implementor like this [link](https://github.com/chrisp22/hello-finagle-thrift-java/blob/master/src/main/java/zdavep/hello/HelloServiceImpl.java).
5. Your Server main should now use the Implementor to create a listening Port like this [link](https://github.com/chrisp22/hello-finagle-thrift-java/blob/master/src/main/java/zdavep/hello/HelloServiceServer.java).

Thus all i did and now am able to run a thrift binary api that is much Scalable.